# java, jsp query chinese characters in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, cjk

The scenario:

1.) User inputs Chinese text to search and submits form

2.) A Java servlet has query to search for that text in MySQL DB.

```
queryString = "Select * from Table where field LIKE '"%+ inputtedChineseText +%"' ";
```

This query does not return any result. If the inputtedChineseText text is "官话" ; and I print it:

```
System.out.println( inputtedChineseText.length() );
System.out.println( new String("官话").length() );
```

it has different length results...

So, how do I convert `inputtedChineseText` to be exactly the same as a coded "官话" so that my query could produce results, I already tried this:

```
queryString = new String(queryString.getBytes("utf-8"),"utf-8");
results = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Still no results.

Anyone?

Comment: What is your JSP pages content-type? I had similar issues until I added the <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %> and also added a meta tag to my <head> section <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

you can set your SQL table's characater encoding as GBK